# Problem connecting to migrated database in Oracle SQL Developer

Tags: database, oracle, oracle-sqldeveloper, database-migration, oracle12c

Using Oracle SQL Developer I have migrated a very simple SQL Server 2012 database (with only 1 table) to Oracle 12c. Everything went as expected and the report looks as follows.
[image]

But when I try to connect the migrated database (Name - DummyDatabase) with username = DummyDatabase and Password = DummyDatabase, I am getting login failure issue as shown below. What might have went wrong?
[image]

Comment: Having a user (schema) with 'database' in the name is slightly confusing. Did you specify the new user's password as part of the migration - and if so are you sure the case matches exactly? As you presumably have privileged access, you could always use that to reset the password. But since it's 12c you should also check if you're connecting to the right container, if this isn't a standalone database.

Comment: @AlexPoole - Pardon me as I am new to Oracle. Yes, before starting the actual migration I have created a user (ex: c##mwrep), created a connection with that user and associated a migration repository to that connection. I have also ensured that user has "CONNECT, RESOURCE, CREATE SESSION, CREATE" privileges. But still I am unable to connect the migrated database.

Answer (score 0):

Finally, I have figured out a fix. The login was failing because the user (i.e., DummyDatabase) itself is not created. This could be because of SQL Developer running generated script (i.e., master.sql) using container DB connection. And Oracle 12c won't allow any user to be created without "c##" prefix in container DB. Hence to fix this I have executed the following command to change the default behavior and then run the generated script in SQL Plus.

```
alter session set "_ORACLE_SCRIPT"=true;
```

Comment: you can't do ANYTHING in a container / cdb - you need to make your migration target a pluggable database (PDB)